# Calculating Cosine Similarity in Julia for K-Means

Tags: julia, k-means, spherical-kmeans

I am making with an implementation of K-means clustering in Julia.

**Figure out, and implement a modification of k-means that alternatively measure similarity by the angle between vectors.**

So I assumed that one could use Cosine Similarity for this, I have made the code work with regular K-means by calculating th squared Euclidian Distance, by this:

```
Distances[:,i] = sum((X.-C[[i],:]).^2, dims=2) # Where C is center, Distances are added using the i-th center
```

I tried to do this by using cosine similarity such as this:

```
Distances[:, i] = sum(1 .- ((X*C[[i], :]).^2 /(sum(X.^2, dims=2).*(C[[i],:]'*C[[i],:]))))
```

But this seems to not be working.

Have I misunderstood the question or am I implementing it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my [Beta Machine Learning Package](https://github.com/sylvaticus/BetaML.jl), module [Utils](https://sylvaticus.github.io/BetaML.jl/stable/Utils.html), I implemented the distances as:

```
using LinearAlgebra
"""L1 norm distance (aka _Manhattan Distance_)"""
l1_distance(x,y)     = sum(abs.(x-y))
"""Euclidean (L2) distance"""
l2_distance(x,y)     = norm(x-y)
"""Squared Euclidean (L2) distance"""
l2²_distance(x,y)    = norm(x-y)^2
"""Cosine distance"""
cosine_distance(x,y) = dot(x,y)/(norm(x)*norm(y))
```

I then use them in the cluster module.
Note that you need the standard library package `LinearAlgebra`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by using the CosineDist function from [Distances](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distances.jl/blob/fa867d59098dd848fd71bc48005a1bf858928a47/src/metrics.jl#L399-L412) github. Although one could also manually calculate the distance using the code supplied in the Github or other implementations.

How I did this, was to calculate the distance for each data point to the i-th cluster center.

```
Distances[:, i] = [evaluate(CosineDist(), X[j,:], C[[i],:]] for j in 1:300] # Or the length of X
```